# How to get value of selected items from listbox and storing into a variable

Tags: php, sql

I use a list box and its item comes from the database i looped it over using while loop. All i want is when I select an item from the dropdown listbox, i can also get other selected item value from the database. Like in the picture, if i select an item in the drop down i need to get its quantity from the database. Thanks 
[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you using any Framework?

Comment: No im not im just using native php code. I already have the database value into my drop down. What i dont know is that how can i get the quantity of the selected items. (The quantity is also on the database)

Comment: @Nebi can you recommend some documentation on how to solve my problem?

Comment: Native PHP? You mean Core PHP?
Ok then you can do. there are 3 methods. `1.using AJAX`  and  `2.using pre-loaded Javascript Array` and `3. Add a custom Data-Property`. Choose a method (It depends on how large is your data)

Answer (score 0):

If you use Jquery framework,you can get it like this

```
1:var options=$(“your css selector”); //choose the item

2:options.val(); //selected value

3:options.text(); //selected text
```

Comment: Is it inside form? if so you can grab the value using $_post['fieldname'] or $_GET['fieldname']

Answer (score 0):

You can try like -

1. Try getting selected item's div class. Suppose could be "selected"
2. Get div value by below  -

   var selectedListval =  $("#ddlist").find('.selected').val();
3. Do null check for selectedListval and execute ajax call to function - which will serve purpose of fetching quality of selected dropdown item Refer http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ 
   for ajax syntax.
4. after null check ,bind Quantity value to the Quantity textbox.

Hope this helps you.